# Custom urls in WordPress involving page slugs

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a page called 'Cars' with slug `cars`. Is it possible that the page works as normal at this URL `http://example.com/cars/` and `http://example.com/cars/audi/` can be used to show something some special content that is not a child-page but from a custom php file.

Can I add URL rewrite rule like this `add_rewrite_rule('^cars/([^/]+)/?','index.php?make=$matches[1]','top');`

I'm trying it but it doesn't work stucks in a redirect loop, looks like WordPress is trying to find a child-page may be, I could be wrong.

Comment: The idea of calling custom php file is not good over here. Instead you should elaborate what you are interested to do and what you have done so far so that the community can help. Also in WordPress we use [Page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) instead of custom php files. Hope this might help you.

Comment: The problem here is I don't want to create child pages in WordPress.

Comment: @MohammadMursaleen I have edited the question please have look

Comment: What I understand is you want the child page to act different from parent which is why you are avoiding child page. You can do this by simply [selecting custom Page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) for your child page (-audi) containing the php functions that you want to execute in it. Still I'm interested to know the reason you are avoiding child page thing.

Comment: If I create a child page called audi, the url then becomes /cars/audi/ but will it let me open the same child page if the url is accessed like this /cars/jeep/ or /cars/bmw/

Comment: Yes sure if you are planning to have different content for different cars like BMW, jeep and so on with same page template each as separate child page of cars as parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exact piece of code works, the reason for redirect was some other plugin.

To create as many child pages you want dynamically you just need to this just hook it to 'init' hook.

```
add_action('init','my_custom_rewrite_rules' );

function my_custom_rewrite_rules(){
    add_rewrite_tag( '%make%', '([^/]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule('^cars/([^/]+)/?','index.php?make=$matches[1]','top');
   //or To go to a published page.
    add_rewrite_rule('^cars/([^/]+)/?','index.php?pagename=page-slug&make=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

If you want to use a custom file just do this

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'myown_cars_display' );    

function myown_cars_display($template) {
    if ( $make = get_query_var('make') ){
        include('templates/cars-make.php' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules, just open the permalinks page in settings and you are done.